# py4j running inside docker generate bind errors

Tags: python-3.x, docker, airflow, py4j

I'm using a custom `airflow` container and pip package `pyhdfs-client`.
However `pyhdfs-client` uses `py4j` and need to start a java gateway on a random ephemeral port, but it seems that a lot of pyhdfs client I instanciate in my code doesn't start because :

```
Exception in thread "main" py4j.Py4JNetworkException
    at py4j.GatewayServer.startSocket(GatewayServer.java:788)
    at py4j.GatewayServer.start(GatewayServer.java:763)
    at py4j.GatewayServer.start(GatewayServer.java:746)
    at py4j.GatewayServer.main(GatewayServer.java:851)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:390)
    at py4j.GatewayServer.startSocket(GatewayServer.java:786)
    ... 3 more
```

I've tried to instanciate 30 of this small python code on my computer and inside my airflow docker and it works perfectly on my computer but I have a lot of binding error in docker.

```
from pyhdfs_client.pyhdfs_client import HDFSClient

a = HDFSClient(load_local=True)
file= 'hdfs:///any/hdfs/filepath'

ret,out,err= a.run(['-ls',file])
print('ret: {}{}out: {}{}err: {}'.format(ret,'\n', out,'\n', err))
a.stop()
```

**Edit 1:**
I start a small script like this:

```
for i in {1..30}
do
  python script.py &
done
```

I didn't try with a sleep timer but I run 30 at a time with need for 2 ephemeral ports per script with more than 25000 available. Race condition seems very unlikely, I will try with `sleep 1`.

**Edit 2:**
If you wonder, I execute the shell script in both a bare metal machine and inside my airflow container using interactive shell.

Comment: race condition? How do you instantiate the 30 clients?

Comment: @alexis answered in edit 1, I will try it seems unlikely though.

Comment: can you show us how you run your docker image. I mean the command you are using and parameters used thanks

Comment: @blackbird you have the shell script that runs 30 instance of the python script.  if this shell script runs inside a docker container binding error and most of them will note work. If I execute the same shell script on a bare metal machine everything is OK.